# TypeError:Error#1009:Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite

code:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,released);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,pressed);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);

var isRight = false;
var isLeft = false;
var isSpace = false;
var gravity = 10;

function  released(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        isRight = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        isLeft = false;
    }
}
function  pressed(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        isRight = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        isLeft = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        isSpace = true;
    }
}

function loop(e:Event)
{
    if(player.y <= 496){
        player.y += gravity;
    }
    if(isRight){
        player.x += 10;
    }
    if(isLeft){
        player.x += 10;
    }
    if(isSpace){
        if(player.y >= 466){
            player.y -= 1;
            gravity = -10;
        }
        else{
            gravity = gravity * -1;
            isSpace = false;
        }
    }
}
```

full error is:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   Untitled_2_fla::MainTimeline/loop()[Untitled_2_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:38]

I don't understand what it's trying to tell me. Plz help. Thanks.

Comment: Your player clip is undefined. Have you given the MovieClip an instance name of 'player' and added it to the stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the loop function is called before the player object is initialized. so you should added the little code. refer a this.

```
function loop(e:Event)
{
    if(!player) return;

    if(player.y <= 496){
        player.y += gravity;
    }
    if(isRight){
        player.x += 10;
    }
    if(isLeft){
        player.x += 10;
    }
    if(isSpace){
        if(player.y >= 466){
            player.y -= 1;
            gravity = -10;
        }
        else{
            gravity = gravity * -1;
            isSpace = false;
        }
    }
}
```